# Show error message if blank, if populated then show iFrame

Tags: visualforce, error-messages, iframe

*Okay so I'm just going to preface this with the fact that I'm very new to the whole Apex thing, and I really appreciate your help!*

**Here's the scenario:**

I've managed to make a snazzy Visualforce page for an iFrame, which is working fine (although it's not parsing the bit appended to the URL, not that big a deal).

What I want it to do though, is display an error message (or error page, I don't really mind) when the Case.Objective_Folder_Link__c field is blank, to prompt the user to populate it.

Here's the code for the iFrame part, I just have no idea where to go from here to add if statements for an iFrame and error messages:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" showHeader="false">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:iframe src="{!Case.Objective_Folder_Link__c}?logo=false&menu=false&nav=false&profile=false&header=false" scrolling="true" height="1000px" id="theIframe"/> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Well, you are starting off with a very nicely asked and formatted question. Nice one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add a `rendered` attribute to your `<apex:pageBlock>`, and add an `<apex:pageMessage>` as well.

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:pageMessage rendered="{!ISBLANK(Case.Objective_Folder_Link__c)}"
        severity="ERROR" summary="some error message" />
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(...))}">
        <apex:iframe ... />
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Just a note, with this sort of error message it is often a good idea to just move the copy to a `Custom Label`, where any admin in the org can configure it. Then you would change your markup slightly:

```
<apex:pageMessage rendered="{!...}" severity="..." summary="{!$Label.My_Error_Message}" />
```